# Beginner coding chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot

already installed sqlite3 but somehow I keep getting this message

```
import squlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-05'
sql_transaction-[]

connection = sqlite3.connet('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c =connection.cursor()
```

this is the message I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\Documents\chatterbot.py\lucious.py", line 1, in <module>
    import squlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'squlite3'
```

Comment: You spelled it wrongly.

Comment: thanks! I appreciate it, its my first project

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import squlite3
```

try

```
import sqlite3
```

The message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'squlite3'
```

says that you named wrong module to import.

Comment: yeah that's what happened for the help